# Как запретить слияние «из» определённой ветки?

Tags: mercurial, hg

Опущу детали того как мы пришли к такому сценарию работы, скажу только что он себя довольно сильно оправдывает.

Вкратце - у нас есть две основные ветки в репо - test и default, пуш происходит на поддомен(test.project.com) где основная ветка тест, а там уже настроен хук, который автоматом толкает на основной домен(project.com), где стоит основная ветка default.

Работа ведётся в новых ветках под конкретные задачи, затем сливаемся, если задача не критичная, то сразу с default, если что-то масштабное то сливаем с тестом, тестируем, затем сливаем с дефолтом ветку задачи(не тест).

На данный момент слияние ветки задачи с тестом, дефолтом носит скорее наблюдательный характер, т.к. нет страховки от ошибки что какой-нибудь новичок не сольет тест с дефолтом, да и сами можем не досмотреть.

Хотелось бы узнать - можно ли как-нибудь поставить запрет на слияние двух веток(test и def)? Так же как поставить запрет на слияние из ветки test в ветку задачи(чтобы случайно не перетянуть всё тестовое к себе в ветку, а потом из своей ветки в def)?

Comment: наверное следует сделать хук (в гите они есть, если ли в меркуриале - не знаю), который бы просто обрабатывал ситуацию мержда. И если есть тестовая ветка - отказывался.

Comment: Хуки в мекруриале есть, у нас настроены минимальные(при коммите вытягиваются все изменения с сервера), как конкретно запретить что-либо не знаю и гугл не очень подсказывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первой же ссылке поисковика нашлось с кодом на питоне - https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HookExamples

Comment: Да, спасибо, на первый взгляд показалось достаточно сложным